# how to align the form to the right?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i am tying to have the h3 aligned with the form so the form goes to the right and the h3 to the left and both of them to be centered ?

```html
<section style="background-color: #00CDCF; background-image: url(./images/services/contact.jpg);">
  <div id="newsletterform">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h3 style="color:#EF7F1A;">Subscribe to our Newsletter</h3>
      <form action="send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter"><input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" /><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button">
        <div id="response"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `float: right` and `float: left`?

Comment: Please note, this is not a place to ask for links to external tutorials. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.”_

Comment: if you tried floats and they didn't work, try using display:flex; justify-content: flex-start;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use flex and learn more about flexbox

```css
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-color: #00CDCF; background-image: url(./images/services/contact.jpg);">
  <div id="newsletterform">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h3 style="color:#EF7F1A;">Subscribe to our Newsletter</h3>
      <form action="send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter"><input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" /><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button">
        <div id="response"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks a lot man i really appreciate !! i don't know y the hate they block my question and i got 5 dislikes i didn't ask someone to make the code ready for me i asked for advice

Comment: yeah no problem just check flex tutorial enta lebnene

Comment: yes sir i am a Lebanese living in turkey